# What's the meaning of "-D" in other swift flags

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In Xcode's Build Settings, we always use "-D XX" in "Other Swift Flags". Whats the purpose and the proper use of "-D"?

And what's the result if we don't use the prefix "-D"

Answer (score 9):

-D denotes an identifier you define for use with build configuration statements like the builtins os(), arch(), and swift().

See Apple documentation: [Swift Programming Language: Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html)

> A build configuration statement allows code to be conditionally compiled depending on the value of one or more build configurations.
>
> Every build configuration statement begins with #if and ends with #endif. A simple build configuration statement has the following form:
>
> ```
> #if build configuration
>   statements
> #endif
> ```
>
> Unlike the condition of an if statement, the build configuration is evaluated at compile time. As a result, the statements are compiled and executed only if the build configuration evaluates to true at compile time.
>
> The build configuration can include the true and false Boolean literals, an identifier used with the -D command line flag, or any of the platform or language-version testing functions listed in the table below...

Answer (score 2):

-D defines a macro to be used by the preprocessor